# Force user re-authentication after they change their Login Password

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I 'm having a problem with my windows form project. I have a function for user change password of their login in SQL Server. User will do login on windows form with old password. After navigating to the change password function, they will be asked to provide new password and old password. New and old password are received, using this SQL command to change password

```
ALTER LOGIN [LOGIN_NAME] 
    WITH PASSWORD = 'NEW_PASS', OLD_PASSWORD = 'OLD_PASS';
```

But the problem is user also use old password and new password login to SQL Server in this session. After I stop and start project again, the old password had expired. I want when user submit new password, the application has to force their login again with it. Could anyone give me solution?

Thanks a lot!

P/S: I think I should talk more about the way user connect to database.

I'm using a connection string like this:

```
Program.connstr = "Data Source=" + Program.servername + ";Initial Catalog=" + Program.database + ";User ID=" + Program.mlogin + ";password=" + Program.password;
```

A user connects to a database with a authorized account in that database, and performs the tasks necessary. And the change of password will update the password of connection string.

Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you create a new connection for every request to SQL database (that's how you should actually do), you can create some sort of SQL connection factory, which will create connections for your users. When this factory catches an SQL exception like `login failed for user`, switch to `Your password is expired` window, and ask for credentials again.

```
public class SqlConnectionFactory
{
    public static SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = $"Data Source={Program.servername};Initial Catalog={Program.database};User ID={Program.mlogin};password={Program.password};";
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        } catch (SqlException se) when (se.Number == 18456) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your password is invalid. Try to login again.");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}


// Everywhere in your code
SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection().
```

Probably, you need a more beautiful approach than closing the application, but this is just a demo.
You may also want to create some methods for your `SqlConnectionFactory` like `ExecuteAndReturnReader`, which will create a connection, create a command, and return its reader after execution.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Obviously, i don't want to close the application anymore. I had read this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx 
They said that: "For performance reasons, when a password is reset in SQL Database, the connection will not be re-authenticated, even if the connection is reset due to connection pooling". So i think the problem is connection is still remain old infos. If I can force it renew this connection my problem may be solved.